# Cannot iterate over tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I'm using the tensorflow.data.Dataset api by tensorflow. However I need to create datasets on the fly filtering out elements other dataset. While training goes well and I can iterate over the training set and the dev set, when I reinitialize the iterator with a new dataset that I just created with a filter, i receive the following exception:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Function tf_predicate_5HKZIzWZBv8 is not defined.
```

I'm using the following function to create an initialiser out of a dataset:

```
self.iterator.make_initializer(dataset)
```

where self.iterator is defined as follow:

```
self.iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(ds_types, ds_shapes)
```

Do you guys have any idea about why this is happening? Note that it happens if I call make_initializer after I have created a session, run a dataset, and then create a new initializer. If after the creation I also recreate the Session everything works (except the fact that all the variables have to be reinitialized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and I'm sharing in case somebody will run into this problem. The thing is that, as I'm defining a new dataset after the session has been initialised it, it doesn't have the new operation I'm adding for the new dataset (In this case I'm using a new filter everytime I create a new dataset) and that's why the session can't find the operation. To overcome the problem I defined all the datasets I needed to use before the session is initialised and I used a filter that takes as input a placeholder so that I always use the same filter feeded everytime at iterator init time with the right value.